# Share Location function to add in chat app

Tags: android, ios

I am developing carpool app where chat function is added to communicate rider taker and car owner.

I want to provide "Share Location" facility in chat box. Similar to WhatsApp. How can I do that ?

Also, is this feature paid when we use Google Maps ?

Expert's guidance would be very much appreciable.

Thank you.

Trying for chat api.